# Common interface for these shapes

Tags: java, swing, oop, java-2d

I need to read input from a file and draw the appropriate shape. The shape can be a rectangle, ellipse, circle or a line. I know how to work with all these. However, I was wondering if I could use a common interface and work with each of them.

I mean, I wish I could have something defined as:

```
Shape currentShape;
```

and then I can do:

```
currentShape = new Rectangle(-);
currentShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(-);
```

and so on.

However, I cannot access the exclusive methods of the objects using the currentShape.

What is the alternative?
*PS: I'm using the swing class.*

Comment: *"However, I cannot access the exclusive methods of the objects using the currentShape."* why do you need to

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Actually, in this case, you're right. But would be handy to know how do deal with this though when the case arises.

Comment: But again, why? You can use reshape to change the bounds of the shape, it can be painted . What functionality are you trying to get to?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot access the methods for the dynamic type (Rectangle, Double etc..) because the static type is a parent (Shape). But here's how you can cast it:

```
Shape currentShape;
currentShape = new Ellipse2D.Double();

if(currentShape instanceof Ellipse2D.Double){
    Ellipse2D.Double tmpShape = (Ellipse2D.Double) currentShape;

    // Code goes here
} // else if (same for Rectangle, or any other child of Shape)
```

Comment: @Grendan you  are welcome, please if you don't have other questions, mark it as solved :)